# How to push to a remote git branch on Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push

I have this repo on GiLab:

```
https://gitlab.com/testrepo/api.git
```

There's a branch on this repo called `testing`. How can I push to the `testing` branch of this repo ?

If I do:

```
git push origin master
```

It'd push my master to probably the master of the repo.

Comment: are you currently on a different branch than `master` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the command:

```
git push origin <your_local_branch>:<remote_branch>
```

to push on any branch in git. In your example, this would be equivalent to running:

```
git push origin master:testing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this if you push on any branch in git

If nothing works out go from the basic, create a new branch and go to that branch by git checkout branch_name and make the required changes in the code, than add ., commit and for pushing the local changes to git branch use below command. It should work.

*$ git push --set-upstream origin Name_of_the_branch*

Answer (score 0):

```
git push origin
```

worked for me. But make sure, you are on the remote-tracking branch (origin/testing).

To move to the remote tracking branch, first make sure you do

```
git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/testrepo/api.git
git fetch origin
git checkout "testing" "origin/testing"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, "https://gitlab.com/testrepo/api.git" is your repo, and this already has a branch name of "testing".

In order to add your local changes to "testing branch" kindly do the below steps:

- Clone the repo in your IDE( ex: VS code)
- Checkout to the branch "testing" using
  git checkout -b testing
- Make your desired changes and save it run all the command listed below
- git add .
- git commit -m "Im adding my changes"
- git push or git push origin 'testing'